# Python KivyMD Function

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivymd

I need to make a function, that takes count function from another non kivy file, and paste it return into MDLabel after clicking the button

```
another file function
def count(TYPE, R11, R22, R33, method='', E11=0, E22=0, E33=0, UU=0, code1=''):


#MyApp button
ConturButton = MDRectangleFlatButton(
        text = 'Рассчитать методом\nконтурных токов',
        font_size = '14',
        size_hint=[0.7, 0.10],
        pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4},
        on_press = self.root.current = 'ResResScreenenter code here'
```

#Here is My function, i just need to put it into on press
global R1, R2, R3, E1, E2, E3
R1 = R1Input.text
R2 = R2Input.text
R3 = R3Input.text
E1 = E1Input.text
E2 = E2Input.text
E3 = E3Input.text
ResultForContur = count('THREERES', R1, R2, R3, method='CONTUR', E11=E1, E22=E2, E33=E3, code1=''.join(code1))
ResResScreen.add_widget(MDLabel(text=ResultForContur))

I was trying to fix it like 4 hours, and try lot of variants, but i need help.

Comment: What variants have you tried?